# How to stop discord.py bot incrementing more values than expected in SQLite database?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I've recently implemented an SQLite database into my discord.py bot in an effort to teach myself SQL in a fun and more meaningful way. It works as intended with a slight issue. The function of the cog is to increment a counter for each discord user everytime they send 'brilliant' in the chat. However, it is incrementing the value for each user several times when they send 'brilliant' and sometimes users that have not said 'brilliant' pop up in the database. The original code:

```
import discord, sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands

class brilliant_count(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        if message.content.lower() == "brilliant" or "brilliant!":

            conn = sqlite3.connect(r"./cogs/brilliant_count.db")
            c = conn.cursor()

            # Get the user data
            user = message.author

            # Check if the user is already in the database
            c.execute("SELECT count FROM brilliant_counter WHERE discord_id=?", (user.id,))
            result = c.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                # User is not in the database, add them with a count of 1
                c.execute("INSERT INTO brilliant_counter (discord_id, discord_username, count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user.id, user.name, 1))
            else:
                # User is in the database, increment the count
                count = result[0]
                count += 1
                c.execute("UPDATE brilliant_counter SET discord_username=?, count=? WHERE discord_id=?", (user.name, count, user.id))

            # Commit the changes to the database
            conn.commit()

            # Close the database connection
            conn.close()



async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(brilliant_count(bot))
```

I figured it might be because the 'on_message' event listener in the cog is being triggered multiple times for a single message, perhaps because the bot is in multiple discord groups.

Jacobson has only said 'brilliant' a few times and Rin has never sent 'brilliant' but their numbers are exceedingly high.

[image: pic]

Doing some research led me to this:

```
        if message.content.lower() == "brilliant" and not message.processed:
            message.processed = True
```

But the above code doesn't work with discord.py and I can't seem to find any other documentation for it. I'd appreciate some advice on what to do next. many thanks.

EDIT: Fixed. Replaced

```
if message.content.lower() == "brilliant" or "brilliant!":
```

with:

```
if (message.content.lower() == "brilliant") or (message.content.lower() == "brilliant!"):
```

As with the first line, the bot was counting it as true and incrementing every single message sent to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but this is to long for a comment:

```
message.content.lower() == "brilliant" or "brilliant!"
```

does not work as you expect it to.

```
if 1==2 or "brilliant!":
    print('hi')
```

will print because even the 1==2 is false the "brilliant!" in itself would be true (every non empty string is true). Please note the () in the next line, it does nothing but in my oppinion it helps a lot while reading code.

I am not sure if you want to trigger the counter if the message ONLY consists of the word "brilliant" but if the condition should either be:

```
if (message.content.lower() == "brilliant") or (message.content.lower() == "brilliant!"):
```

or maybe

```
    if "brilliant" in message.content.lower():
```

if you would also count "super brilliant".

Comment: thank you, much appreciated with the explanation, i will add this to my bot

Comment: Also, this may have fixed it. I will test it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, it was just some incorrect logic in my code which you explained above.